# Problog - probabilistic graph example

Tags: prolog, logic, probability

I am going through the following example on Problog [probabilistic graph](https://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/problog/tutorial/basic/04_pgraph.html)

I tried to computed probability of path from 1 to 5. Here are my manual computations

```
0.6*0.4+0.1*0.3*0.8 = 0.264
```

However, Problog returns `P(path(1,5)) = 0.25824`

Am I computing it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't just add up all the probabilities for the different paths. To see that, just assume that both paths from 1 to 5 had a probability of 0.7 each. You would get a probability of 1.4 which is clearly wrong (meaning that it is impossible that there is no path).

The way to calculate the probability for either of two events A and B is to get the probability of neither being true and then looking at the inverse of this event.

```
P(1->2->5)    = 0.24
P(1->3->4->5) = 0.024
P(either)     = 1 - (1 - 0.24) * (1 - 0.024)
              = 1 - 0.74176
              = 0.25824
```

Sorry for probably bad terminology, my statistics knowledge is a bit rusty.